# React Hooks in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**Background**

I have a web application written in vanilla javascript and HTML. I'm trying to find a way to gradually convert it to a react app. For that, I am trying to create new features using react components.
This app is using Typescript on top of Javascript and we are not using Webpack or any bundlers.

**Scenario**

Here is the sample code I'm working on

```
<body>
   <div id="my_container"></div>     

   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
   <script src="myFile.js"></script>
</body>
```

**myFile.tsx**

```
interface WelcomeProps {
  name: string,
 }

 const Welcome: React.FunctionComponent<WelcomeProps> = (props) => {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
 }

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#my_container');
ReactDOM.render(<Welcome name="World"/>, domContainer);
```

I manually compile this code to javascript then I transpile it using `npx babel --watch .\ui\react\ --out-dir .\ui\ --presets react-app/prod` and it works fine. I can see my component being rendered on the page.

**Problem**

The thing that I'm confused about is that I cannot use React Hooks like `useState()` in the component. 
If I add something like `const [dummyValue, setDummyValue] = useState(0);` in my typescript file, it obviously fails as it does not recognize `useState`. On the other hand, if I import them like

`import {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

it doesn't work either. I see in the debug mode that `react_1` is an empty object.

**UPDATE**

Importing libraries like this, causes ReactDOM to be an empty object. Not sure why though.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface WelcomeProps {
  name: string,
 }

 const Welcome: React.FunctionComponent<WelcomeProps> = (props) => {
  const [dummyValue, setDummyValue] = useState(0);
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
 }

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#my_container');
ReactDOM.render(<Welcome name="World"/>, domContainer);
```

Comment: `useState` is a valid hook. You should be able to use it. Have you tried it?

Comment: not importing it, gives: `Cannot find name "useState"` error in the TypeScript file

Comment: What is your error if you `import { useState } from 'react';` and then try `const [dummyValue, setDummyValue] = useState(0);`

Comment: @Diesel See the update please

Answer (score 0):

1) The [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook is a valid React hook. It should work just fine. You refer to the [official](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) documentation for the list of hooks, and how to use them.

2) In addition to importing the `useState` hook, you will also need to import the `React` package, in order to allow Babel to detect React and JSX syntax.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
```

If `esModuleInterop` is set to `true`, you can simply do this instead:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

3) It will be sufficient to use `React.FC` the declaration of your functional component.

```
const Welcome: React.FC<WelcomeProps> = ({ name }) => {
  return <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh Can I check your typescript settings? The stuff on `tsconfig.json?` `esModuleInterop` should be `true`

Comment: Ok.. This is weird. It is probably some other issue in your code, but for now, to fix your question, you will need to do this instead: `import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` Let me update my answer.

Comment: unfortunately still no luck after updating the `import` statements.